# Visio Service in SharePoint 2016 regularly corrupts/deletes cache

Tags: 2016, visio, cache

I have a SharePoint 2016 farm that is running Visio Services. Quite often the vent viewer is flooded with a error event "Failed to access the cache." and the ULS complains about missing cache files;

"Failed to generate raster diagram for file https://WEBAPP.COMPANY.COM/SITE/VISIOFILE.vsdx page Image1 Error : System.IO.FileNotFoundException: X:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\16.0\Data\VisioServer\VisioCachea83b9056-071f-4739-8e08-8b4d03bb3bf8\VisioBundled17c818763d0434d8b2aea9c2ba59031.cache"

The permissions are set for the directory mentioned above, have event tried granting all service accounts access to it. I have recreated the service a couple of times.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have host-based antivirus running on the SharePoint server(s)?

Comment: That could be it. I need to check with the server administrator. If they do, I´ll let them ignore that filepath.

Comment: No, there is no antivirus running on the server. But a good guess.